# Enlarge image full screen and hover to scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replicate this example, where you can click on the image, it enlarges full screen and then you can hover to scroll up and down.

www.uniqlo.com/us/product/women-slim-fit-jeans-143893.html#69|/women/bottoms/jeans/slim-fit/|

Not sure where to start, I'm using slick slider as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Start by dividing the task into different steps.

- Create the required markup. You can prefer having an unordered list of images. Each list item can consist of the thumbnail and the original image and the original image being kept hidden at initial load.
- Add event listener to the list and listen for when an image was clicked.
- If and image was clicked, load an overlay that comes on top of the screen to cover it all. Then absolutely position the large image and show it on top of that overlay with a higher `z-index`
- For scrolling, there are may techniques you can use. One of them would be to calculate the position of your mouse pointer and changing the `scrollTop`  values to get the scroll-on-hover effect.

No code is pasted since you asked for a place to start. This should pretty much give you an idea of what needs to be done. Let me know if you need help with code.

NOTE - I am behind a proxy that does not let me open the URL. I have tried to imagine what you want and answered.